# Show some view, only if iOS 14, SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14

I want to show a Text view say:

```
Text("Welcome to iOS 14")
```

if the user is using iOS 14.

If the user is using other iOS versions I Want to show a different Text view, say:

```
Text("Welcome to Different iOS version")
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is the thing that you call a TextView?  `TextEditor`?

Comment: Text view means Text("some text")

Comment: Set the development target to iOS 13.x and bring Text Editor to the content view.  Xcode will show you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion

    var body: some View {
        if systemVersion.starts(with: "14" ) {
            Text("welcome to ios 14")
        } else {
            Text("Welcome to Different iOS version")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's he or she is talking about.

Comment: may be, will wait .

Comment: It's helping me, but it's not what I am talking about. I can't upvote you because I don't have enough reputation otherwise I would upvote you.

Comment: do you want only to show some view in iOS 14 and another view when not iOS 14?

Comment: Two different views say text or image I want to show based on users iOS version.

Comment: Yes. Your last question is what I am talking about.

Comment: i changed the answer bit, check it out, let me know wether i have understand ur problem?

Answer (score 1):

This also looks at versions 14.1, 14.2 etc...

Return a string and you can add as many houses as you want. You can apply the concept to anything.

```
struct ContentView: View {  
  
    public var systemVersion: String? {
        return UIDevice.current.systemVersion // "14.2" in my case
    }
    
    var getMessageSystem: String {
        guard let versionOS = Double(systemVersion!)
            else { return "Not a valid iOS version" }
        switch versionOS {
            case _ where versionOS > 14: return "welcome to iOS 14"
            case _ where versionOS > 13: return "welcome to iOS 13"
            case _ where versionOS > 12: return "welcome to iOS 12"
            default: return "welcome"
        }
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(getMessageSystem) // welcome to iOS 14
    }
}
```